# Is possible to make the options of properties dynamic in business template editor of WSO2?

Tags: dynamic, properties, wso2, siddhi

Context: 
in Wso2, to make Siddhi apps dynamic, one uses business rules. 
This business rules are created from templates like this: 
[image]

Rule templates have some properties for each attribute. In this properties there are **options** to make a list of possible values for attributes. 
What I wonder is how to make these options dynamic, like calling from an external API or from the DB.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are not supporting this feature for now in Stream Processor. You can request this feature by opening an issue in WSO2 GitHub repository.